# how to create an adapter file on kotlin

Tags: kotlin, adapter

i was using  a code from old tutorial

i uesd this code

```
class Adapter(context: Context , var names :ArrayList<String> , var state :ArrayList<String>)
    :ArrayAdapter<String>(context , R.layout.item , names) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item , null)
        view.imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        view.textView10.text = names[position]
        view.textView12.text = state[position]

        return view
    }
}
```

is this true

Comment: What is it true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.